# Knowing type of generic in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class, says :

```
MyClass<T>
```

Inside a method of this class, I would like to test the type of T, for example :

```
void MyMethod()
{

    if (T == String)
        ...
    if (T == int)
        ...
}
```

how can I do that ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: As an aside, why would you want to do this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't, normally, due to type erasure. See [Angelika Langer's Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for more details.

What you *can* do is pass a `Class<T>` into your constructor, and then check that:

```
public MyClass<T>
{
    private final Class<T> clazz;

    public MyClass(Class<T> clazz)
    {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void myMethod()
    {
        if (clazz == String.class)
        {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

Note that Java does not allow primitives to be used for type arguments though, so `int` is out...

Comment: Ew. Java is gross for this kind of thing.

Comment: which honestly you shouldn't need if you design your classes properly.

Comment: I understand, maybe my desing is bad.
I have a view that can be applyed to 2 models, except for some little things depending on the type of the object model.
I don't want to create 2 views that are quite the same, but they are not working exactly the same.

Comment: With all respect for "proper design", I dislike it when a language tells me what "proper design" is. Notwithstanding that this might be bad design, I find "Java does not need to do this because you designed it improperly" is possibly not the best reply.

Answer (score 8):

Because of type erasure you can't... mostly. But there is one exception to that. Consider:

```
class A {
  List<String> list;
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (Field field : A.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
      System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", field.getName(), field.getGenericType());
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
list: java.util.List<java.lang.String>
```

If you need the class object, this is how you generally handle it:

```
public <T> T createObject(Class<T> clazz) {  
  return clazz.newInstance();
}
```

ie by passing the class object around and deriving the generic type from that class.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to cletus one exception I've mine: [super type tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html). The super type token will preserve the type information.

`new Type<Set<Integer>>() {}`

The type information can be retrieved with [Class.getGenericSuperClass](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

```
if (object instanceof String)
   System.out.println("object is a string");
```

Comment: I think that's actually a reasonable point given the question.

Answer (score 0):

As it was already stated you can get only generics-related information available at the static byte code level.

It's possible to [resolve type arguments values](http://denis-zhdanov.blogspot.com/2009/12/improved-type-arguments-resolving.html) and [check if one type may be used in place of another](http://denis-zhdanov.blogspot.com/2009/12/advanced-type-compliance-framework.html) then.

Answer (score 0):

if you have subclass `B extends A` that should match, too, the approach `clazz == A.class`. Doesn't work. You should then use `A.class.isInstance(b)` where b is an object of type B.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do different things for different types would it still be generic?