# Getting unexpected parameter type when calling Method.getParameterTypes()

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
public abstract class NumberRangeParameter<T extends Comparable<T>> 
extends ComplexParameter{

    private T lower;

    public void setLower(T lower) {
        this.lower = lower;
    }

}
public class IntegerRangeParameter extends NumberRangeParameter<BigInteger> {}
```

Now, if I run this (`irp` is an instance of `IntegerRangeParameter`):

```
Method[] methods = irp.getClass().getMethods();
for (Method m : methods) {
    Class<?>[] parameterTypes = m.getParameterTypes();
}
```

If I step this code on the debugger and evaluate `parameterTypes` I get `[interface java.lang.Comparable]`, but I was expecting it to be BigInteger...

Can someone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into the [Type Erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_generics#Type_erasure) issue which is inherent when using Java generics due to the requirement for backward compatibility. Generic parameters are mainly there for *compile-time* type checking, and the information is lost (for the most part) at run time. Please check out the link provided for more.

**Edit 1**
Also please check out this similar SO thread: [get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection)

Comment: Thanks, i figured it had something to do with that, Java generics still puzzle me sometimes. By the way, I wonder what kind of error I will get if I invoke the method with a subclass of `Comparable` but not `BigInteger`.

Comment: You will likely not see any compile-time errors (one of the risks of using reflection with generics) but would likely get a class cast exception at run time.