# how to find Collection type?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have two variables

```
Collection<Service> services = new ArrayList<Service>();
Collection<Subscription> subscriptions = new ArrayList<Subscription>();
```

and I have the following method, I was wondering how can I find the value of "?" in this method, or how can I find if services was passed or subscriptions was passed?

```
myMethod(Collection<?> myCollection) {

   if (myCollection is of type Service) {
      // process service
   }
   else if (myCollection is of type Subscription) {
      // process subscription
   }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you need knowledge of the type, you shouldn't be using a wildcard. Just have separate methods for each type of collection.

Comment: I have to use the same method name aka overloading, but at compile time myMethod(Collection<Service>) and myMethod(Collection<Subscription>) will be considered as duplicate methods, hence I was trying to use if/else in one method.

Comment: You're right; I forgot about type-erasure.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. Java has erasure-based generics, which means that the type parameters are not available at runtime.

If your collection is not empty, you can do an `instanceof` on the first element or something, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I also thought that doing the instanceof on first element would help but I was wondering if there is another way but looks like there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Using that if-else construct in a generic method defeats the purpose of generics.  If you need to know the type of what is being passed in at runtime, it really shouldn't be generic and you should write a separate method for each type.

Comment: I agree, it is a bad design, but I am not the designer, the design was given to me and I can't change it. The design was done by our "design team"...

Answer (score 2):

You can't (except [by using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection/5301116#5301116)), since the generic type parameter gets erased during compilation.

And I would recommend you rethink your design rather than trying to solve it with generics. Passing arbitrary types of collections into the same method is a recipe for problems in the long run.

Comment: Even reflection can't get at the type parameter; like you say, it's erased already!

Comment: @Chris, I couldn't find the original post I saw about this, but found another one, see the link in my answer.

Comment: Re edit: that's to get at the type of a _parameter_, not of the passed-in object. Alas, the type parameters of actual live objects are actually erased.

Comment: @Chris, in my understanding this is what the OP is after. At any rate, this is an academic question, because it certainly is a bad idea :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no Java way of doing exactly that. Type erasure gets in the way. And if you need to do so, it is also probably a design issue.
But if you must, there is  horrible way to do almost that:

Change your variables to

```
Collection<Service> services = new ArrayList<Service>(){};
Collection<Subscription> subscriptions = new ArrayList<Subscription>(){};
```

Note the {} after the (). You are not creating an ArrayList, but a anonymous class that inherits from ArrayList. And type erasure does not apply there. So you can tell the real type by doing something like

```
private static Class<?> detectType(Collection<?> col) {
    return (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) col.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

That method will return the actual class. It does work, it is disgusting. It is up to you.