# One of Two Generic Lists parameters in method

Tags: java, android, generics

I have a method in my Android app that can either display from a `List` of `Drawables` or `Strings` (representing the image URLs).

I tried to make two constructors but got the type erasure error. Now I am using a generic argument and check a member for being a String to represent the URL, like so. In the alternate case I assume that it will be a List of Drawables. Something like this:

```
setImages(List<?> images) {
    this.images = images;
    if (String.class.isInstance(images.get(0) ) ) {
        isImageUrl = true;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this better, somehow preserve type safety ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use 2 separate methods?

```
void setImages(List<Drawable> images) {
 // do something
}

void setImagesFromStrings(List<String> images) {
 // do something else
}
```

Comment: You could always have different method names if they are setting the images in different ways, e.g. `setImages(List<Drawable> images)` and `setImagesFromStrings(List<String> images)`

Comment: That's actually a pretty good idea. Now why didn't I think of that... I'm actually using this in a constructor as well so I'm going to overload that by using a dummy parameter. Type safety preserved problem  solved.

Comment: And to think you're answer started as the most unreasonable... lucky you didn't get a downvote... and look at you now.... good work

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no real way to do that.

There has been some interesting solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection/9271840#9271840), but I don't think it applyes for you.

Personnally, I prefer to pass the class as a parameter for the method like

```
setImages(List<? extends T> images, Class<T> clazz) {
    this.images = images;
    if ( clazz == String.class  ) ) {
        isImageUrl = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better object oriented way to solve you problem would be to have an intermediate interface that provides the method you are looking for, but this will force you to wrap `String` into something else

```
interface Displayable {
  public boolean isRealImage();
}

class StringImage implements Displayable {
  public String name;
  public boolean isRealImage() { return false; }
}

class DrawableImage implements Displayable {
  public Drawable drawable;
  public boolean isRealImage() { return true; }
}

setImages(List<? implements Displayable> images) {
    this.images = images;
    if (images.get(0).isRealImage()) {
      isImageUrl = true;
    }
}
```

Of course this solution, while quite overkill, is meant to allow you whatever you need to do with your classes.

Comment: It does seems a bit of overkill and I probably won't use it but at least type safety is preserved so +1

Comment: Yes, you asked for a type safe solution not for a slick one.. in a verbose language like Java they are often at antipodes ;)