# How to implement a generic wrapper for a ResultSet-like API?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have an third-party RPC-API that provides an interface similar to that of [`java.sql.ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) (for reading values) and [`java.sql.PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) (for writing values). Assume it looks something like this:

```
public interface RemoteDeviceProxy {
    public void setBoolean(Boolean value);
    public void setInteger(Integer value);
    // ...

    public Boolean getBoolean();
    public Integer getInteger();
    // ...
}
```

I want to write a wrapper for this API that uses generics to create instances of specific types:

```
public class <T> RemoteVariable {
    private final RemoteDeviceProxy wrappedDevice;

    public RemoteVariable(RemoteDeviceProxy wrappedDevice) {
        this.wrappedDevice = wrappedDevice;
    }

    public T get() {
        // should call wrappedDevice.getBoolean() if T is Boolean, etc.
        // how to implement?
    }

    public void set(T newValue) {
        // should call wrappedDevice.setBoolean(newValue) if T is Boolean, etc.
        // implement using instanceof
    }
}
```

How can I implement the getter in my generic wrapper? I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13974262/160206) which explains a similar scenario in depth, but I am not able to transfer this to my problem. Specifically, when I write this:

```
public T get() {
        Type[] actualTypeArguments = ((ParameterizedType) getClass())
                                         .getActualTypeArguments();
    }
```

I get a compiler error saying I cannot cast to `ParameterizedType`, and I do not understand why. Can anyone explain how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
public class <T> RemoteVariable {
    private final RemoteDeviceProxy wrappedDevice;
    private final Class<T> clazz;

    public RemoteVariable(RemoteDeviceProxy wrappedDevice, Class<T> clazz) {
        this.wrappedDevice = wrappedDevice;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public T get() {
        if(clazz == Boolean.class){return clazz.cast(wrappedDevice.getBoolean());}
        else if(clazz == Integer.class){return clazz.cast(wrappedDevice.getInteger());}
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Since instances of `RemoteVariable` are created from a factory anyway, this isn't even ugly in client-code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I thought over this quite a while and finally came up with a different approach:

First I added a getter to you `RemoteVariable` class:

```
protected RemoteDeviceProxy getWrappedProxy() {
    return wrappedProxy;
}
```

Second I created a builder interface that will be used by a factory later:

```
public interface RemoteVariableBuilder {
    public <T> RemoteVariable<T> buildNewVariable(RemoteDeviceProxy wrappedProxy);
}
```

Then I created non generic sub classes for `Boolean`...

```
public class RemoteBooleanVariable extends RemoteVariable<Boolean> implements RemoteVariableBuilder {

    public RemoteBooleanVariable(RemoteDeviceProxy wrappedProxy) {
        super(wrappedProxy);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> RemoteVariable<T> buildNewVariable(RemoteDeviceProxy wrappedProxy) {
        return (RemoteVariable<T>) new RemoteBooleanVariable(wrappedProxy);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean get() {
        return getWrappedProxy().getBoolean();
    }

    @Override
    public void set(Boolean value) {
        getWrappedProxy().setBoolean(value);
    }

}
```

... and Integer ...

```
public class RemoteIntegerBuilder extends RemoteVariable<Integer> implements RemoteVariableBuilder {

    public RemoteIntegerBuilder(RemoteDeviceProxy wrappedProxy) {
        super(wrappedProxy);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> RemoteVariable<T> buildNewVariable(RemoteDeviceProxy wrappedProxy) {
        return (RemoteVariable<T>) new RemoteIntegerBuilder(wrappedProxy);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get() {
        return getWrappedProxy().getInteger();
    }

    @Override
    public void set(Integer value) {
        getWrappedProxy().setInteger(value);
    }

}
```

actually eclipse created most of the code once it knew base class and interface.

The final step was to create a factory

```
public class RemoteVariableFactory {
    private static final Map<String, RemoteVariableBuilder> BUILDERS = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        BUILDERS.put(Boolean.class.getName(), new RemoteBooleanVariable(null));
        BUILDERS.put(Integer.class.getName(), new RemoteIntegerBuilder(null));
        // add more builders here
    }

    public static <T> RemoteVariable<T> getRemoteVariable(RemoteDeviceProxy wrappedProxy, Class<T> typeClass) {
        RemoteVariableBuilder remoteVariableBuilder = BUILDERS.get(typeClass.getName());

        if (remoteVariableBuilder == null) {
            return null; // or throw an exception whichever is better in your case 
        }
        return remoteVariableBuilder.buildNewVariable(wrappedProxy);
    }
}
```

Now we are ready to create new RemoteVariables...

```
RemoteVariable<Boolean> var1 = RemoteVariableFactory.getRemoteVariable(new RemoteDevice(), Boolean.class);
RemoteVariable<Integer> var2 = RemoteVariableFactory.getRemoteVariable(new RemoteDevice(), Integer.class);
```

To conclude this let's do a quick comparison to the answer of Eng.Fouad:

Disadvantage:

- you need to create a new class for every datatype you provide

Advantage:

- you only have to add one line to the static block of the factory and not two new if blocks to the getter and setter in RemoteVariable
- get and set do not have to work through the if-else-blocks every time