# find constructor which has a generic parameter

Tags: java, reflection

how can I find the constructor of a class which get passed a generic parameter. For example such a class:

```
class myClass<T> {
    public myClass(T val1, Long val2 String val3){ 
        ...
    }
}
```

Using the usual reflection approach `getConstructor()` lacks the proper parameters:

```
Constructor<?> myConstructor = myClass.class.getConstructor( ??what here??, Long.class, String.class);
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 6):

Object is the type: `Object.class`

Because of generic type erasure, there is no other more specific type available.

More good stuff here: [get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection)

e.g., for

```
public class Bar<T> {
   private T t;

   public Bar(T t) {
      this.t = t;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return t.toString();
   }
}
```

This will return "foo":

```
Class<?>[] paramArray = {Object.class};
Constructor<?> myConstructor = Bar.class.getConstructor(paramArray);
String foo = "foo";
Bar myBar = (Bar) myConstructor.newInstance(foo);
System.out.println(myBar);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's fairly straight forward.

```
Constructor<T> myConstructor = myClass.class.getConstructor( T val, Long.class, String.class);
```

If you want a string, it looks like this:

```
Constructor<String> myConstructor = myClass.class.getConstructor( String val, Long.class, String.class);
```

If you want a int, it looks like this:

```
Constructor<int> myConstructor = myClass.class.getConstructor( int val, Long.class, String.class);
```

Comment: ints can't be used as a generic, you have to use Integer. That last example would be Constructor<Integer>...

Comment: Have you tested this code? Does this even compile: `myClass.class.getConstructor( String val, Long.class, String.class);`?