# Java generics - obtaining actual type of generic parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have read [Get type of a generic parameter in Java with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection) post and it made me wonder how that would be possible. I used the solution that someone posted and using the code

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
Class actualTypeArguments = (Class) ((ParameterizedType) l.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

This, however does not work for me, resulting in

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
```

If I remove the class cast, the type of the actual argument is `E`, which is the type definition from List interface.

My question is, therefore, am I doing something wrong here? This behaviour is something I would have expected anyway, since the types are supposed to be erased during compile time, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you use only works in some very specific cases, where the actual type parameter is known (and stored) at compile time.

For example if you did this:

```
class IntegerList extends ArrayList<Integer> {}

List<Integer> l = new IntegerList();
```

In this case the code you showed would actually return `Integer.class`, because `Integer` is "baked into" the `IntegerList`.

Some libraries (ab)use this trick via the use of type tokens. See for example the [GSON class `TypeToken`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html):

> Represents a generic type `T`. You can use this class to get the generic type for a class. > For example, to get the generic type for `Collection<Foo>`, you can use:
>
> ```
> Type typeOfCollectionOfFoo = new TypeToken<Collection<Foo>>(){}.getType()
> ```

This works because the anonymous class created in here has compiled-in the information that its type parameter is `Collection<Foo>`.

Note that this would not work (even if the `TypeToken` class wouldn't prevent it by making its constructor protected):

```
Type typeOfCollectionOfFoo = new TypeToken<Collection<Foo>>().getType()
```

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc will tell you what you are doing.

[`Class#getGenericSuperclass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass%28%29) states

> Returns the Type representing the direct superclass of the entity
>   (class, interface, primitive type or void) represented by this Class.
>
> If the superclass is a parameterized type, the Type object returned
>   must accurately reflect the actual type parameters used in the source
>   code. [...]

The direct superclass of `ArrayList` is `AbstractList`. The declaration is as such in the source code

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
    implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

So if you print out the `Type` object returned by it, you will see

```
java.util.AbstractList<E>
```

and therefore [`ParameterizedType#getActualTypeArguments()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments%28%29) which states

> Returns an array of Type objects representing the actual type
>   arguments to this type.

will return the `Type`

```
E
```

since `E` is the actual type argument used in the `ArrayList` class definition.

Answer (score 1):

The method you described does ONLY work, when the Generic Type is Set due to inheritance, because then its known during compile time:

```
 public class SomeClass<T>{

 }

 public class SpecificClass extends SomeClass<String>{

 }
```

For this example, you can use the method and you'll get back "String.class".

If you are creating instances *on the fly* it won't work:

```
SomeClass s = new SomeClass<String>(); //wont work here.
```

Some common work around is, to pass the actual class as a parameter for later reference:

```
 public class SomeClass<T>{
    Class<T> clazz

    public SomeClass(Class<T> clazz){
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public Clazz<T> getGenericClass(){
       return this.clazz;
    } 
 }
```

usage:

```
 SomeClass<String> someClass= new SomeClass<String>(String.class);

 System.out.println(someClass.getGenericClass()) //String.class
```

Actually you don't even need the Generic type for such an scenario, because Java would do the same thing, as if you would handle the "T" as `Object`. Only advantage is, that you can define getter and Setter of T and don't need to typecast Objects all the time. (Because Java is doing that for you)
(It's called Type Erasure)