# How does MessageBodyReader know what the generic type is?

Tags: java, jersey

I have a `MessageBodyReader` with the following class:

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class TransactionMessageBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader<Transaction<Customer>> 

boolean isReadable(Class<?> type,
                       Type genericType,
                       Annotation[] annotations,
                       MediaType mediaType)
```

And I have the following REST endpoint:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("trans")
public Response checkStatus(Transaction<Customer> transaction) { ... }
```

In my debugger I have a breakpoint on `isReadable` and it hits the breakpoint before calling the `checkStatus` method. Good so far. I can see in my debugger that the `genericType` says `Transaction<Customer>` ... in other words, it knows about the type information. How can it possibly know the type information when Java type erasure erases it to just be `Transaction` at runtime? I see that the `genericType` is made up of an `ParameterizedType` which I believe is used to pass type information around (to get around the type erasure problem). However, how is Jersey populating the `genericType` automatically? Because I never specified type information except in the method headers that I posted above.

Also, a second question: if Jersey 'automatically' knows so much about my types, why do I need a `MessageBodyReader` at all? Isn't there some easier way to use generics with Jersey/REST endpoints and make it "just work"?

Comment: Actually, it is because there is the `MessageBodyReader` implementation that it magically works. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19860393/java-generics-obtaining-actual-type-of-generic-parameter

Comment: @Tunaki I know, but why? How does the MessageBodyReader actually know the type information? (It is also type erased -  right?).

Comment: I suspect this of using the standard trick: type erasure erases generics from _objects_ but not _classes_.

Comment: There's a dark magic trick as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15999255/1743880.

Comment: @Tunaki I kind of get it but not fully. I didn't create an anonymous class anywhere. In the example given, the author creates an anonymous class and passes it to a method. I didn't do that anywhere. So wouldn't my type still be erased at runtime?

Comment: Not exactly but you did implement an interface with the parameterized type (so it's conceptually the same thing). The Spring framework uses the same techniques to get the actual parameterized type. I found this other related answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2226038/1743880

Comment: It should _"just work"_. Can you post a small, minimal project on github of it _not working_.

Comment: @peeskillet My Transaction class is defined as Transaction<T extends Person>. I found that using jersey-media-json-jackson I get a ClassCastException "Person cannot be cast to Customer" so clearly it isn't creating the expected type, it's creating the base class type instead. When I switched to using Genson instead, that problem went away. In summary... I tried to make an example for you but the problem didn't replicate. However the problem definitely exists when using certain JARs, maybe it's a bad configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html#isReadable-java.lang.Class-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.annotation.Annotation:A-javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType-).

> `genericType` - the type of instance to be produced. E.g. if the message body is to be converted into a method parameter, **this will be the formal type of the method parameter as returned by `Method.getGenericParameterTypes`**.

Generic parameterization in classes, methods, and fields is maintained in the corresponding `.class` files. This is obviously necessary for compilation. You wouldn't be able to package and use Java classes as a library if this wasn't the case.

Reflection exposes this type information (and more).

Jersey basically scans your classes for handler methods, ones annotated with `@POST` and the like and retrieves corresponding [`Method`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) objects. Once it has that, it can use [`Method#getGenericParameterTypes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericParameterTypes--)

> Returns an array of `Type` objects that represent the formal parameter
>   types, in declaration order, of the executable represented by this
>   object. Returns an array of length 0 if the underlying executable
>   takes no parameters.
>
> **If a formal parameter type is a parameterized type, the `Type` object
>   returned for it must accurately reflect the actual type parameters
>   used in the source code.**

On other words, the `Type` has to represent both the parameter's raw type and its parameterization, if it has one.

So Jersey retrieves those types and feeds them into your `MessageBodyReader`. The expectation is that your implementation should be able to handle the `genericType`.

I don't know Jersey that well, but if it follows the same strategy as Spring MVC, it will simply iterate over all the `MessageBodyReader` instances that were registered. It doesn't actually care about its type (eg. your `TransactionMessageBodyReader`), that's why it relies on `isReadable`. It could theoretically keep a mapping of types to `MessageBodyReader` implementations, but that becomes unwieldy in the end and less flexible. In any case, an application doesn't typically have that many types/formats it can serialize to, so iterating a few objects isn't that big of a deal.

---

Since Java 8, you also have access to [`Executable#getParameters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Executable.html#getParameters--) (`Method` is a subtype of `Executable`).

---

Here's an example of what Jersey could do

```
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Method method = StackOverflow.class.getDeclaredMethod("method", List.class);
        Type[] parameterTypes = method.getGenericParameterTypes();
        for (Type parameterType : parameterTypes) {
            System.out.println(parameterType.getClass());
            System.out.println(parameterType);
            ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) parameterType;
            System.out
                    .println(parameterizedType.getRawType().getTypeName() + "<" + parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0].getTypeName() + ">");
        }
    }

    public String method(List<StackOverflow> parameter) {
        return "example";

    }
}
```

prints

```
class sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl
java.util.List<com.example.StackOverflow>
java.util.List<com.example.StackOverflow>
```

Comment: Thanks. So if Jersey can 'see' all the method types, why do I need to write a MessageBodyReader at all? Without one, Jersey does not seem to know the generic type parameters. Other posters in this discussion have said that libraries use tricks like anonymous classes to discover the type parameters. So it doesn't seem to be as simple as just 'it's in the class file so it's available'.

Comment: @KyleM Read the type and do what with it? Jersey might have a default implementation for handling JSON, XML, and standard formats. But once you need something more complicated or less common, you need your own implementation.

Comment: My point is that from the checkStatus() method I posted above, Jersey has no way of knowing what the generic type parameter is. Hence the necessity of the MessageBodyReader...

Comment: @KyleM It does a have way, as stated in the answer. The `MessageBodyReader` is for defining a _Contract for a provider that supports the conversion of a stream to a Java type._

Comment: @KyleM If you have a parameter of type `MyPojo`, where/how should Jersey generate a value of that type in order to invoke your method? That's what `MessageBodyReader` gives you.

Comment: Jersey automatically generates simple types. It's only when you start using generic parameters that it stops working. I can ascertain from this discussion that it has to do with Jersey not knowing what the generic type parameter is using the @Consumes method alone. Once you implement the MessageBodyReader, this somehow clues Jersey in to what the Generic type parameter is. That is the mechanism I am trying to understand better. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111901/discussion-between-kylem-and-sotirios-delimanolis).