# Determining runtime type of a Java generic

Tags: java, generics, reflection, runtime

I have a generic class that has a method which needs to know the runtime type:

```
public class SomePOJO<TYPE> {
    // ... lots of code

    public void doSomething() {
        // Obtain runtime type of TYPE and do something with it.
    }
}
```

I tried following the [most upvoted answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection), and implemented `doSomething()` like so:

```
public void doSomething() {
    //                                                            |<-- error starts here
    Class clazz = (Class)((TYPE)getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

However this is throwing a compiler error:

> The method getActualTypeArguments() is undefined for the type TYPE

I am compiling against JDK 1.6u34 - where am I going wrong - and why?

Comment: Due to type erasure you cannot do that! You need an instance of `<TYPE>` to call `getClass()` on.

Comment: Try following that answer more precisely by casting to the same type it does ...

Comment: Thanks @meriton however if you look at my code closely, the only thing I changed from the other example was changing "`ParameterizedType`" to "`TYPE`" which is necessary for my example...

Comment: Well, that change is why you get the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in comments, due to type erasure you cannot get type in runtime.
I would suggest to use a factory method like:

```
class SomePOJO<TYPE> {
    // Variable to store runtime type
    Class<TYPE> klass;
    private SomePOJO(Class<TYPE> klass) {
        this.klass = klass;
    }

    // Lots of code

    public void doSomething() {
        // Do what you want with type
        System.out.println(klass);
    }

    // Static factory method
    public static <T> SomePOJO<T> createPojo(Class<T> klass) {
        // Save class object that represents type to SomePOJO instance
        return new SomePOJO<T>(klass);
    }
}
```

It will help you to preserve type for doSomething() method.