# How to determine the class type of generic property in java without reflection?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class:

```
public final class Param<T>
{
    private final String name;
    private T value;
    public Param(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }   

    public void setValue(T value) { this.value = value;}
    public T getValue() { return value; }
}
```

I would instantiate it in the following way:

```
Param<Long> foo = new Param<>("bar");
Param<String> baz = new Param<>("foo");
```

I want to add a `public boolean validate(String value)` method to this class, which would do something like the following:

```
public boolean validate(String value)
{
    try
    {
        if (this.value instanceof String)
            return true;

        if (this.value instanceof Long)
            this.value = (T) Long.valueOf(value);
        else if (this.value instanceof Integer)
            this.value = (T) Integer.valueOf(value);
        //Snip.. a few more such conditions for Double, Float, and Booleans
        return true;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My question is, will the above method work, for correctly determining the 'type' of `T` and for correctly casting `string value` to `T value`? Or should I use a different approach for validating the parameters?

Comment: Duplicate of [SO: get type of a generic parameter in java with reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection)?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl That question is completely different, mine doesn't have anything to do with reflection. In fact, I want to do it without reflection.

Comment: Do you seriously intend on manually checking every single type known to humankind?

Comment: @2rs2ts No, I only have a few possible types that i'll be assigning to this class, so I would have only checked against them.

Comment: Have you tried to actually use this class? Since I think it's rather useless: you should delete the type parameter `T` altogether. It isn't going to serve any purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java generic types are not reified, meaning you need to have some other mechanism for keeping track of them if you need runtime information about them.

A common approach is to pass in a `Class<? extends T>` token in the constructor:

```
public final class Param<T>
{
    private final String name;
    private T value;
    private Class<? extends T> type;
    public Param(String name, Class<? extends T> type)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public boolean isString() {
        return String.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    } 
}
```

Comment: You're a C-sharpie, right? It's `boolean` in Java :)

Comment: Actually, I'm Java first, but I've been forced to do PHP work lately.

Answer (score 3):

So, uh, you want to:

```
if (this.value instanceof Long)
    this.value = (T) Long.valueOf(value);
```

If `value` is a `Long`, convert it to a `Long`, cast it to a `Long`, and store it back in `value`. What?

No. No, I don't think that's going to work.