# How to read class types of generics parameters using Java reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a class `BaseClass<X, Y, Z>`. And I implement the class as `SuperCar implements BaseClass<Color, Engine, Foo>`. So now i need to get those X,Y,Z values by using reflection on `SuperCar` class. Is this possible ?

Comment: I guess it is not possible, remember that Java generics use erasure, the type parameters are "forgotten" after compilation. 

E.g. `ArrayList<Car>` is compiled to `ArrayList<Object>` - compiler doesn't compile if you try to put a `Helicopter` in `ArrayList<Car>`, but the runtime only sees `ArrayList<Object>` and would happily allow it.

Comment: There is a excellent answer on this post to explain how to do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inspect the type parameters for the superclass, having the `Class` of the `SuperCar`:

```
SuperCar car = new SuperCar();
ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) car.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
Type[] superClassTypes = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments();
for (Type type : superClassTypes) {
    System.out.println(type.getTypeName());
}
```

This should give you:

```
Color
Engine
Foo
```

Answer (score 1):

i guess you want to have something like this:

```
ParameterizedType types = (ParameterizedType) SuperCar.class.getGenericInterfaces()[0];
for (Type type : types.getActualTypeArguments()) {
    Class<?> cl = (Class<?>) type;
    System.out.println(cl.getName());
}
```

instead of printing the name you can do whatever you like with it