# How to check whether Java generic type is subclass of Comparator?

Tags: java, generics

When I try to complete a task, there's one case need to be handled: throw exception of generic type of class is not comparable. Refer to the following code for the detail.

```
 public class C <T>
    {
        public C()
        {
            // throw exception if T is not comparable
        }
    }
```

Comment: This class can also accept class which is not subclass of Comparator; and there is another function to assign there comparator for it. If key is un-comparable and not comparator is not assign, throw exception.

Answer (score 2):

You can enforce the generic to be a subclass of `Comparator` like so:

```
public class C <T extends Comparator> {
    public C(){
    }
}
```

As you see in the below code, it would be a good idea to add another generic (here it is `K`), which you supply to `Comparator`, since the generic of `Comparator` will otherwise default to `Object`.

```
public class C <K, T extends Comparator<K>> {
    public C(){
    }
}
```

You generally use this in the form of `T x K`, where `T` is the generic, `x` is `super` or `extends` and `K` is the class/interface.

Comparator [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this class can also accept class which is not subclass of Comparator; and there is another function to assign there comparator for it.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that the generic parameter T is a `Comparable`by writing:

```
public class C <T extends Comparable>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1)  Make it T extends Comparable, so you know it will always be.

2) In the constructor, pass Class < T > as a parameter, so you'll know at runtime what T is. (because it's erased)

Comment: A subclass of a generic class can get at the generic type using reflection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection

Answer (score 1):

Add a generic constraint, that is would be better since it will be handle it at compile time rather than throw an exception on runtime.

```
class C <T extends Comparable>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should  verify that your parameter T is `Comparable`.

```
 public class C <T extends Comparable>
```

This is the same if you want a generic type implements some interface.

```
public class C <T implements <interface what you want> >
```

Or if you want that were a superclass of another one.

```
public class C <T super <class what you want> >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always want the type `T` to implement `Comparable` you can enforce this as follows.

```
public class C<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

    public C() {

    }
}
```

This is better than throwing an exception at runtime. It will not even compile if someone tries to write `new C<some non-Comparable type>()`. Note that `Comparable` is a generic type, so it should not be used without type parameters; it should not simply be

```
public class C<T extends Comparable>
```

If the type `T` will not always implement `Comparable`, but you want a specific constructor that will only work for `Comparable` types, then the answer is that you can't do this with constructors, but you can do it with a static method.

```
public class C<T> {

    public C() {
        // Constructor that works with any T
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> C<T> getNew() {
        C<T> c = new C<>();
        // Do stuff that depends on T being Comparable
        return c;
    }
}
```