# Using generic types with String.format in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class like this:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    private T var;

    public MyClass(T init_value) {
        var=init_value;
    }

    ...
}
```

Now I would like to add `toString()` method to it, which returns the concrete type and value of `var`. I try something like this:

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("MyClass object initialized with type %s and value %s", T, var);
}
```

This, however, does not work, as I have a problem that type variable T seems not to be visible as normal variable. Namely, I get an error:

```
T cannot be resolved to a variable
```

How can I overcome this problem and make a type variable printable?

Comment: Think about <T> like it's alias. So what should be <T> to make your code compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already have object of class `T` you can use `getClass` on it:

```
String.format("MyClass object initialized with type %s and value %s", var.getClass().getSimpleName(), var);
```

If you don't have `var`, you option would be to provide argument of type `Class<T>` explicitly:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    private Class<T> clazz;

    public MyClass(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Type of T: %s", clazz.getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

You have to do this, because type `T` is usually not accessible in runtime due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). The only exception is when you define class that extends explicitly parameterized class: `class MyIntegerClass extends MyClass<Integer>`. In this case type parameters could be accessed via [reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection).