# Get generic type at runtime: works in some cases, but not in others - why?

Tags: java, generics, dynamic

I am trying to get the generic type of a class or interface implementation. I am aware that this has some risks and quirks, but I'm trying to understand what is possible.

Here's my example code:

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Main {

    public interface MyInterface<T> {
    }

    public static class BaseImpl<T> implements MyInterface<T> {
    }

    public static class TypedImpl extends BaseImpl<Integer> {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LinkedList<MyInterface<Integer>> instances = new LinkedList<>();

        // 1. anonymous class from interface
        instances.add(new MyInterface<Integer>() {
        });

        // 2. class extending interface
        instances.add(new BaseImpl<Integer>());

        // 3. class with pre-defined generic type
        instances.add(new TypedImpl());

        for (MyInterface<Integer> instance : instances) {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");

            Class clazz = instance.getClass();
            Type genericSuper = clazz.getGenericSuperclass();
            Type[] genericInterfaces = clazz.getGenericInterfaces();
            Class target = null;

            System.out.println("class: " + clazz.getName());
            System.out.println("generic super: " + genericSuper);
            System.out.println("generic interfaces: " + Arrays.asList(genericInterfaces));

            // attempt to 'extract' generic type
            if (genericSuper instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                target = getGeneric((ParameterizedType) genericSuper);
            } else if (genericInterfaces.length > 0) {
                for (Type genericInterface : genericInterfaces) {
                    if (genericInterface instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                        target = getGeneric((ParameterizedType) genericInterface);

                        if (null != target) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("TARGET: " + target);
        }
    }

    // attempt to get type argument
    public static Class getGeneric(ParameterizedType type) {
        if (MyInterface.class.isAssignableFrom((Class) type.getRawType())) {
            Type typeArg = type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];

            try {
                return (Class) typeArg;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                System.out.println("cast exception for '" + typeArg + "'");
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

The output of this is:

```
----------------------------------------------
class: Main$1
generic super: class java.lang.Object
generic interfaces: [Main.Main$MyInterface<java.lang.Integer>]
TARGET: class java.lang.Integer
----------------------------------------------
class: Main$BaseImpl
generic super: class java.lang.Object
generic interfaces: [Main.Main$MyInterface<T>]
cast exception for 'T'
TARGET: null
----------------------------------------------
class: Main$TypedImpl
generic super: Main.Main$BaseImpl<java.lang.Integer>
generic interfaces: []
TARGET: class java.lang.Integer
```

So, my goal is to have the value of the `target` variable be `Integer.class`. For the anonymous class (#1) and the explicitly typed implementation (#3) I am able to find the target as expected. Why does it work in these instances and not in the case of #2 (BaseImpl instance)? Is there another way to accomplish this? (I am aware of the common workaround of passing the target `Class` via the implementing class's constructor, however I'm interested in doing this dynamically)

I have consulted the following sources:

- [Get type of a generic parameter in Java with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection)
- [Get generic type of class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime)
- [How to get a class instance of generics type T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437897/how-to-get-class-instance-of-generics-type-t)

Thanks a lot in advance,

Abel

Comment: You seem to be looking for http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ResolvableType.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html (Bolds are mine)

> Using Java Generics typically falls into **one of two different
>   situations**:
>
> **Declaring a class/interface as being parameterizable**. Using a
>   parameterizable class. When you write a class or interface you can
>   specify that it should be paramerizable. This is the case with the
>   java.util.List interface. Rather than create a list of Object you can
>   parameterize java.util.List to create a list of say String.
>
> **When runtime inspecting a parameterizable type itself, like
>   java.util.List, there is no way of knowing what type is has been
>   parameterized to**. This makes sense since the type can be parameterized
>   to all kinds of types in the same application. **But, when you inspect
>   the method or field that declares the use of a parameterized type, you
>   can see at runtime what type the paramerizable type was parameterized
>   to**. In short:
>
> **You cannot see on a type itself what type it is parameterized to a
>   runtime, but you can see it in fields and methods where it is used and
>   parameterized**. Its concrete parameterizations in other words.

Particular cases are explained on the page

Answer (score 0):

In cases 1 and 3 the type is part of the reflection data on the classes `Main$1` and `Main$TypedImpl`, thus you can access it.

In case 2 you only have instance data which due to type erasure doesn't contain any type information. Hence you can't access the generic type here.

To further explain:

At runtime the system can't distguish between `BaseImpl<Integer> i;` and let's say `BaseImpl<String> s;`, i.e. due to type erasure both variables `i` and `s` are of type `BaseImpl`.

In contrast `TypedImpl t;` is known to be of type `TypedImpl` and using reflection you can extract the generic type provided in the `extends` or `implements` statement.

*Side note, since you're trying to learn what's possible:*

If you'd define `BaseImpl` as `BaseImpl<T extends Number> implements MyInterface<T>` you could extract the upper bound for `T` from the reflection data on class `BaseImpl`, i.e. you'd be able to know that `T` must be `Number` or a subtype (or implementation in case of interfaces).