# Get a generic class field type with Java Reflections

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have the following class structure:

```
public class GenClass<T> {
    public T elem;
}
```

I use it in the following way:

```
public class Test {
    public GenClass<UUID> data;
```

Now I want to get the type of elem using the Field object of data(`Test.class.getField("data")`)
But when I use `getType` to retrieve the class the Generic information is stripped away.

How can I map the generic Information from `getGenericType` to the class object to retrieve the field with a correct type?

**Edit:** Since there are some misunderstandings, I try to clarify my problem.
Consider this example:

```
public class AClass<T, Q> {
    public Q elem;
    // some other code using T...
}

public class BClass<T, Q> {
    public T elem;
    // some other code using Q...
}
```

Now I want a function to get the class of elem:

```
public class Test {
    public AClass<UUID, String> a;
    public BClass<Integer, Float> b;

    void do() throws Exception {
        Field aField = Test.class.getField("a");
        Field bField = Test.class.getField("b");

        getType(aField, "elem"); // should return String.class
        getType(bField, "elem"); // should return Integer.class
    }

    Class<?> getType(Field f, String classField) {
        // ???
    } 
}
```

How did I need to implement `getType` to get my desired result?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection

Comment: But I don't know, which of the actual type arguments for the field is used for elem. Maybe I have a class like AClass<T, Q, B> and then declare `B data`. How do I know, that data is the third type argument?

Answer (score 5):

You have the `Type` object corresponding to your field `data`, from calling `getGenericType`.

```
Type t = f.getGenericType();  // f is your Field
```

The [`Type` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) and its implementations represent different cases of what kinds of types could be present here.  Because `data`'s type is `GenClass<UUID>`, parameterized with a type parameter, the `Type` returned here is actually a `ParameterizedType`.

```
ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
```

Generally there could be multiple generic type parameters, but you have only one here.  Call [`ParameterizedType`'s `getActualTypeArguments` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getActualTypeArguments--).

```
Type parameter = pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Yes, we have another `Type` instance, but this one represents the generic type parameter of the `Field`, not the `Field` itself.  Because you supplied a class type in the `Test` class, this `Type` is nothing other than an ordinary `Class` -- `UUID.class`.

```
System.out.println(parameter instanceof Class);
System.out.println(parameter == UUID.class);
```

Output:

```
true
true
```

Comment: Look at my edited question for a better explanation of my problem!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so what you need to do is get both the type parameters on the raw type of your a/b field, and the actual type parameters on the ParameterizedType. The raw type Parameter can then be matched up with the elem field on the A/BClass you're interested in, but then you use that to resolve/match to the the actual type (the arrays line up).

```
public class TestGenerics {
    public AClass<UUID, String> a;
    public BClass<Integer, Float> b;

    void getFieldTypes() throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        Field aField = TestGenerics.class.getField("a");
        Field bField = TestGenerics.class.getField("b");

        Class<?> aFieldElem = getType(aField, "elem"); // should return String.class
        Class<?> bFieldElem = getType(bField, "elem"); // should return Integer.class

        System.out.println("a field, elem field type: " + aFieldElem.getSimpleName());
        System.out.println("b field, elem field type: " + bFieldElem.getSimpleName());
    }

    Class<?> getType(final Field f, final String classField) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        Type genericType = f.getGenericType();
        //going to assume this. In reality you'd want to do an instanceof first
        ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) genericType;
        Class<?> rawType = (Class<?>) pt.getRawType();
        Type[] actualTypeParams = pt.getActualTypeArguments();
        TypeVariable<?>[] rawTypeParams = rawType.getTypeParameters();

        Field classFieldOnF = rawType.getField(classField);

        genericType = getResolvedType(classFieldOnF.getGenericType(), rawTypeParams, actualTypeParams);

        //same here, you'd need to do an instanceof first
        return (Class<?>) genericType;
    }

    private Type getResolvedType(final Type genericType, final Type[] rawTypeParams, final Type[] actualTypes) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rawTypeParams.length; i++) {
            if (genericType == rawTypeParams[i]) return actualTypes[i];
        }
        return genericType;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
        TestGenerics test = new TestGenerics();
        test.getFieldTypes();
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
a field, elem field type: String
b field, elem field type: Integer
```