# How can I obtain the type parameter of a generic interface from an implementing class?

Tags: java, reflection

I have this interface:

```
public interface EventHandler<T extends Event> {
    void handle(T event);
}
```

And this class implementing it:

```
public class MyEventHandler implements EventHandler<MyEvent> {
    @Override
    public void handle(MyEvent event) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

In this clase, `T` parameter is `MyEvent`, that is a concrete implementation of `Event`. How can obtain this using reflection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get type of a generic parameter in Java with reflection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Resolve the type of `T` by the generic interface. E.g.

```
public interface SomeInterface<T> {
}

public class SomeImplementation implements SomeInterface<String> {

    public Class getGenericInterfaceType(){
        Class clazz = getClass();
        ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) clazz.getGenericInterfaces()[0];
        Type[] typeArguments = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments();
        Class<?> typeArgument = (Class<?>) typeArguments[0];
        return typeArgument;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SomeImplementation someImplementation = new SomeImplementation();
    System.out.println(someImplementation.getGenericInterfaceType());
}
```

PS: Keep in mind that the acutalTypeArguments are of type `Type`. They must not be a `Class`. In your case it is a Class because your type definition is `EventHandler<MyEvent>`.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to do anything non-trivial with generics and reflection, consider Guava's `TypeToken`:

```
private interface Event {}

private interface EventHandler<T extends Event> {
    void handle(T event);
}

TypeToken<?> findEventType(final Class<? extends EventHandler> handlerClass) throws Exception {
    final TypeToken<? extends EventHandler> handlerTypeToken = TypeToken.of(handlerClass);
    final Invokable<? extends EventHandler,Object> method = handlerTypeToken.method(EventHandler.class.getDeclaredMethod("handle", Event.class));
    return method.getParameters().get(0).getType();
}

public void testExploreGuavaTypeTokens() throws Exception {
    class MyEvent implements Event {}

    class MyEventHandler implements EventHandler<MyEvent> {
        @Override public void handle(final MyEvent event) {}
    }

    assertEqual(MyEvent.class, findEventType(MyEventHandler.class).getRawType());
}
```

(Note that the `TypeToken` returned by `findEventType()` could contain much richer type information than a `Class` can represent; that's why it's the caller's decision whether to simplify it via `getRawType()`.)