# How do I check both 'instanceof' and also the Generic type of a Java object at runtime?

Tags: java, instance

How do I check both `instanceof` and `isAssignableFrom` of a Java object that uses generics?

If I have this method that checks `instanceof` only, BUT I also want to check that it returns a `Boolean` type as opposed to another type, how would I do this?

```
public void myMethod(ObjectA<Boolean> object)
{
    if ( object instanceof ObjectA ) {
       // then do something
    }
}
```

Comment: You most likely can't, since the type parameter would be erased at runtime.

Comment: I don't understand. You already know at compile time that `object` is a `ObjectA<Boolean>`. This should already be enforced.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  Ok, so your saying I dont need to worry about someone writing code and passing in the wrong object because it will be caught by IDE code introspection before compile time?

Comment: Raw types are always an issue. But that's the client's issue, not yours. It's a misuse of your interface. A client shouldn't expect it to work when using raw types.

Comment: And it's not the IDE, it's just the compiler. I can't call `myMethod(...)` with anything other than a value of type `ObjectA<Boolean>` (except if it's raw).

Comment: And do you think my question is so obvious that it deserves closure rather than a formal answer?

Comment: I do not think so, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the `instanceof` is unnecessary (unless you wanted to check for `null`, in which case you should just check for `null` with `==`).

Your method declaration

```
public void myMethod(ObjectA<Boolean> object)
```

already enforces that callers can only pass values that are of type `ObjectA<Boolean>` or assignable to type `ObjectA<Boolean>`.

In other words, I cannot write code like

```
ObjectA<Integer> notBoolean = ...;
myMethod(notBoolean);
```

the compiler will reject it.

Within your method, since the parameter is of type `ObjectA<Boolean>`, the compiler guarantee is that nothing will get through at runtime that isn't an `ObjectA`. For example, you won't end up with `object` holding a reference to a `Socket` or a `NoSuchElementException` object.

---

The exception to all of the above is expressions having a raw type. Don't use raw types. Here's why:

- [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

With raw types, a client could potentially write

```
ObjectA<Integer> notBoolean = ...
ObjectA raw = notBoolean;
myMethod(raw);
```

and the compiler would forgo the generic type check and allow the invocation (the compiler erases the generic usage in the context of that invocation) .

Your code would presumably then fail at runtime with a `ClassCastException` when trying something like

```
public void myMethod(ObjectA<Boolean> object)
{
    Boolean ref = object.get(); // ClassCastException
                                // returns an `Integer` and attempts to assign it to a `Boolean` variable
}
```

Your `object` would still hold a reference to a `ObjectA` instance, but whatever it might wrap will no longer necessarily be a `Boolean` (I'm assuming `ObjectA` is some kind of wrapper for a `Boolean` value here).

This `ClassCastException` will be more or less equivalent to what you could've thrown anyway.

I wouldn't make a check specifically for this raw usage.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this.   That all makes perfect sense.