# Java reflection - Get actual type of T in a generic interface<T>

Tags: java, generics, reflection, interface

How do I get the actual type of T in a generic interface?

Given the following class:

```
class myClazz {
        private final IGenericInterface<?> genericInterface;

        myClazz(final IGenericInterface<otherClazz> genericInterface){
            this.genericInterface = genericInterface;
        }
}
```

How do I get the simple name of otherClazz out of the constructor using reflection?

I tried the following:

```
String otherClazzString = myClazz.class.getConstructors()[0].getParameterTypes()[0].toString(); //
```

but I do not know what to do next to obtain the simple name of the actual type used in the generic interface.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get type of a generic parameter in Java with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close, but you need to use [`getGenericParameterTypes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#getGenericParameterTypes--), as well as [`getDeclaredConstructors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructors--) (since your constructor is not public):

```
Class<?> cls = (Class<?>) ((ParameterizedType) myClazz.class.getDeclaredConstructors()[0]
    .getGenericParameterTypes()[0]) // first constructor, first parameter
        .getActualTypeArguments()[0]; // first type argument

System.out.println(cls); // prints 'class otherClazz`
```

It should be noted that this code will only work if the type argument of the parameter is a concrete type, otherwise the cast to `Class<?>` will not work. For instance, in the case that the argument is a type variable, `getActualTypeArguments()[0]` will return an instance of [`TypeVariable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/TypeVariable.html) instead of `Class<...>`.