# Get the number of generic type parameters of a class using its instance?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

Is it possible to get the number of type parameters a class has/accepts in Java using its instance? For example,

```
Map<String, Integer> s = new HashMap<>();
int numParams = getNumOfTypeParameters(s); // Should return 2
```

I know that due to type erasure we can't get the type of these parameters but can we also not get the number of parameters?

Comment: Did you look through the methods in `java.lang.Class`?  It's not hard to find.

Comment: ... `Map` always takes 2 parameters. What are you thinking?

Comment: @user202729 Yes I know that but I need this method for *any* generic class' instance.

Comment: ---[Actually you can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection).--- No you can't, see JonSkeet's comment.

Comment: You know that you are supposed to do *serious* research prior posting questions?

Comment: Is this question too trivial to post on SO? We have many beginner questions, and this one (as far as I can see) have not been asked on SO.

Comment: Why are people so eager to close a question that has not been asked earlier and is quite easy to be overlooked by beginners looking through the docs? This is not duplicate, spam, not about programming or anything that needs to be voted closed. SO is sometimes too intimidating to be asking simple questions even when they've not been asked yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as

```
System.out.println(Map.class.getTypeParameters().length); // 2

System.out.println(Class.class.getTypeParameters().length); // 1

System.out.println(Object.class.getTypeParameters().length); // 0
```

Just look at the documentation for `java.lang.Class` and you'l find [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getTypeParameters--).

Comment: Thanks! I overlooked that method in that long list of methods.