# How to get a reference to the `Class<T>` object for a generic class with specific type parameters?

Tags: java, reflection

For instance, I can have

```
Class c = Map.class;
```

But what if I need `c` to refer to the class `Map<String, ValueClass>`?

I want to do something which expresses

```
Class c = (Map<String, ValueClass>).class;
```

My use case is that I need to do this so that I can pass `c` to [getConstructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-)

Comment: if I understand it correctly , you should look at this: [a get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spcecific type `Map<String, ValueClass>` share the same class object with `Map`, so you can not aquire a custom class object.

At run time, `(Map<String, ValueClass>).class` equals `Map.class` because of [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map map = new HashMap();
    Map<String, Integer> anotherMap = new HashMap<>();
    System.out.println(map.getClass().equals(anotherMap.getClass())); // true
}
```

Comment: This explains why what I proposed won't work, but the question of how to get a reference to generic classes with specific type parameters still stands. Unless it can't be done at all, in which case something's broken because that's what `getConstructor` method expects

Comment: Well, then update answer to reflect that claim and I'll accept it if no one disagrees. Then I guess how to deal with `getConstructor` becomes a different question

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to get the static type as you require, you can force your way to it using casts (albeit through raw types):

```
Class<Map<String, Object>> cl = (Class) Map.class;
```

However, as pointed in other comments and other answer, that doesn't help you as, at runtime, your `class.getConstructor()` call will only see `Map.class` anyway.

Just consider the signature of `getConstructor`:

```
getConstructor(Class<?>... parameterTypes)
```

The implementation retrieves the constructor by comparing parameters (check the source of `java.lang.Class.arrayContentsEq(Object[], Object[])`).

To summarize, it boils down to comparing `(Class) cl == Map.class`, and that returns `true` at runtime, which explains why it's no use looking for the generic class instance.

---

The value of `Class<Map<String, Object>> cl` would only be effectual if that were used for static type checking, but in this case, it doesn't help.