# Getting type of parameterized generic type

Tags: java, generics

Here's a simplified method I have to implement:

```
class Sample<T> {
    Class<List<T>> getType() {

    }
}
```

So the solution to it could be:

```
class Sample<T> {

    final Class<List<T>> type;

    Sample(Class<List<T>> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    Class<List<T>> getType() {
        return type;
    }

    static void test() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<List<Integer>> clazz = (Class<List<Integer>>) (Class<?>) List.class;
        Sample<Integer> sample = new Sample<>(clazz);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the warning when instantiating clazz?

Or even better - to avoid passing it in constructor and just get the desired result based on the class type?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get type of a generic parameter in Java with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection)

Comment: Honestly this code looks broken.  I think there's something wrong with the way you're designing it.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish there. If you want to check the class type, you should look for the "instanceof" in Java documentation.

Comment: There's no way to avoid that warning, aside from not doing this at all. There's not really any such thing as a `Class<List<Integer>>`.

Comment: You should probably store `Class<T>` instead, if `List` is always going to be the same.