# Retrieve Advanced Information from Generic Type Parameters

Tags: java, generics

I was wondering if there is a possibility in Java 12 (minimum Java 8 required) to call `T.class` on a generic type parameter, or if there is some workaround?

Since I'm against rewriting the same code logic over and over, I was currious about calling `T.class` to pass any type of Java Object to my method and to write some mapping functionality to handle `Optional<T>` unwrappging logic.

```java
public SpecificEntity specific(final Long id) throws EntityNotFoundException {
    final Optional<SpecificEntity> optional = this.specificEntityRepository.findById(id);
    if (optional.isEmpty()) {
      throw new EntityNotFoundException(SpecificEntity.class, "id", id.toString());
    }
    return optional.get();
  }
```

I wish, that it would be possible to rewrite the above code like this:

```java
public <T> T generic(final Optional<T> optional, final Long id) throws EntityNotFoundException {
    if (optional.isEmpty()) {
      throw new EntityNotFoundException(T.class, "id", id.toString());
    }
    return optional.get();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is to add a single parameter to your function `Class<T>`, where you'd call it like such:

`generic(optionalOfInteger, Integer.class, 0)`, as an example

The other method you might be able to use involves utilizing reflection, and is documented here: [Get type of a generic parameter in Java with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection)

However, keep in mind that reflection-based approaches can be quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be better to use

```
public <T> T generic(final Optional<Class<T>> entityClazz, final Long id) throws EntityNotFoundException {
     ....
     ......
  }
```

This way the user of your method will have to provide the class of the entity he wants to get?