# Get generic type parameters from an object in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am probably wrong with terminology which doesn't help me to google the answer, but the question boils down to this:

I have a set of objects declared like this:

```
public interface ActivationService<T extends Activator> {
    T getActivator(Item item);
}
```

, so the set is declared like this:

```
Set<ActivationService>_activationServices = new HashSet<>();
```

I want to transform it into a map in order to lookup the appropriate "activation service" easier.

```
Map<Class<? extends Activator>, Set<ActivationService>> _actsCache = new HashMap<>();
```

Once I know how to get this `T` parameter from an object of a class, I will be able to do it. How do I get this from an object? The `TypeVariable` interface confuses me.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't

Comment: `Set<ActivationService>` You are using the raw type here btw. It should be `Set<ActivationService<SomeActivator>>`

Comment: I never used reflection myself but I think it is possible to achieve what you want with it. Check this quesiton: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection. However, I'd rather rethink the idea than use the reflection which might come really painful later on. Of course there is no point if you use raw types as Michael mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your interface is `ActivationService<T extends Activator>` you'll probably want to use `Set<ActivationService<? extends Activator>>` as well.

That being said, you should already see that there's a problem getting the actual generic type of a service stored in the map/set because it could be any number of unrelated activators.

To fill the map you could do one of 2 things:

1. Provide a `Class<T> getActivatorClass()` method in the interface and provide an appropriate implementation.
2. Use reflection to get the actual generic type from any concrete implementation, i.e. this would work for `MyActivatorService implements ActivatorService<MyActivator>` but not `MyActivatorService<T extends MyActivator> implements ActivatorService<T>`. (Have a look here on one way how to do that which I've used for years now [there might be a more modern way now]: https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860)

Note that when working with such a service you'd need to use some casts eventually because all you've got is a `ActivatorService<? extends Activator>`, i.e. there's no way to get the actual generic type at compiletime.

Comment: I understand that there are unrelated activators, that's why I decided to group their services.
I think my question is about how to use reflection. The `getActivatorClass` seems to return information already present in an implementation, like implying some extra work for the implementor...

Comment: @fedd yes it's some extra work but since reflection has its caveats using a method like that seems the safest way to go. You could mitigate the effort to some extent by providing a base class that uses reflection to provide an implementation of that method or maybe even a default implementation in the interface itself (although I've never tested this).

Comment: @fedd information about type parameters may not be present in an implementation. For example, it's absent in `class GenericActivationService<T extends Activator> implements ActivationService<T>`.