# how do I get the simple name of a java.lang.reflect.Type in java

Tags: java

```java
public String getSimpleName(Type type){
    //how?
}
```

I can't controll variable passed into `getSimpleName(Type type)` except that it is instance of `Type`.

Of course I know that I can use `p.getType().getSimpleName()` in the following example, but it's not important to solve the following exmaple. what I want to show from it is that if the user (out of my control) passes `p.getParameterizedType()` calling `getSimpleName(Type type)`,he still can get correct result (i.e. List).

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        final Method m = App.class.getMethod("foo", List.class);
        final Parameter p = m.getParameters()[0];
        System.out.println(p.getParameterizedType());
    }

    public void foo(List<String> strings){
    }
}
```

the above will print "java.util.List<java.lang.String>", but I want to get "List".

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Parameter;
import java.util.List;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        final Method m = App.class.getMethod("foo", List.class);
        final Parameter p = m.getParameters()[0];
        System.out.println(((Class<?>)p.getParameterizedType()).getSimpleName());
    }

    public void foo(List<String> strings){
    }
}
```

the above will throw `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get type of a generic parameter in Java with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection)

Comment: No.  That's getting the type of the parameter not the generic type.

Comment: surprisingly `type.getTypeName()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches to getting a what you want from a `Type`.

1. Cast the `Type` object to a `ParameterizedType` and call `getRawType` on it.

   ```
   import java.lang.reflect.*;
   import java.util.List;

   public class App {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
           final Method m = App.class.getMethod("foo", List.class);
           final Parameter p = m.getParameters()[0];
           System.out.println(((ParameterizedType) p.getParameterizedType()).getRawType());
       }

       public void foo(List<String> strings){
       }
   }
   ```

   That outputs "interface java.util.List".  Not exactly what you want, but closer.
2. Use a regex to extract the name you want from `"java.util.List<java.lang.String>"`.

---

But as @deadshot points out, you can get the `Class` for a `Parameter` using `getType()` and then get the name of that via the `Class` API.

Comment: Not sure if it's guaranteed (probably not), but in this case it appears `ParameterizedType#getRawType()` returns an instance of `Class`, which means `getSimpleName()` can be used directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [getType()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Parameter.html#getType--) and [getSimpleName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName--) methods.

```
System.out.println(p.getType().getSimpleName());
```

**Output:**

```
List
```

Comment: I can't limit the variable passed into `public String getSimpleName(Type type)` except that it is instance of Type