# How can I get a field inside a type (<T>) inside an implementation using Reflection on Java

Tags: java

**TLDR: I need a method to get the  being implemented as an interface in a class using reflection. (read the last line too, please...)**

The problem is simple, but I can't solve it, I have an interface EventListener, with the following code:

```java
public @IndexSubclasses interface EventListener<T> {
    public void onEvent(T event);
}
```

And I have an implementation, the JoinEventSampleBase (which is only a sample to be copied), with the following code:

```java
@Scope.Server @FrameworkEvent
public class JoinEventBaseSample implements EventListener<JoinEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(JoinEvent event) {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

I had tried the following on my EventManager:

```java
 Class<?> eventIndication = Arrays.stream(listener.getInterfaces())
       .filter(aClass -> aClass.getName().equals(EventListener.class.getName()))
 .findFirst().get().getComponentType();
```

*It is confuse because it was only a test.*

I got the following **error**:

```sh
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)" because "eventIndication" is null
```

The line that is doing the error after the "eventIndication" var is the following:

```sh
Object instance = eventIndication.getDeclaredField("instance").get(null);
```

**Finally, my objective is access the instance method into the eventIndication field which is into the JoinEvent class in**

```java
implements EventListener<JoinEvent>
```

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc for `getComponentType`? What are you expecting it to return?

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime

Comment: I readed it but I didn't see that this only works in array.
Returns the Class representing the component type of an array. If this class does not represent an array class this method returns null.

Answer (score 0):

It works, thanks (:

My code:

```java
ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) listener.getGenericInterfaces()[0];
Class<?> eventIndication = (Class<?>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```