# Get type of a generic parameter in SpringBoot with reflection

Tags: java, spring, reflections

I have a spring project with several classes "IceCream", "Chocolate" that implements an interface "FoodInterface".
FoodInterface:

```java
public interface FoodInterface{
    String getType();
}
```

IceCream:

```java
public class IceCream implements FoodInterface{
    @Override
    public String getType() { return "ice-cream"; }
}
```

I also have repositories for these classes:

```java
public interface IceCreamRepository extends JpaRepository<IceCream, String>, FoodRepositoryInterface<IceCream> {
    IceCream findAllById(String id)
}
```

To select the correct repository when having the type string (e.g. `ice-cream`) and the string id i have created a FoodRepositoryInterface:

```java
public interface FoodRepositoryInterface<T extends FoodInterface> {
    String getType() {}
}
```

and I changed my repositories to this:

```java
public interface IceCreamRepository extends JpaRepository<IceCream, String>, FoodRepositoryInterface<IceCream> {
    String getType() { return "ice-cream"; }
    IceCream findAllById(String id)
}
```

But I want to be able to have `ice-cream` in one place (in the IceCream class and the same for the Chocolate class).
Therefore I want to get the class of the generic type, call the constructor and call getType() all in the FoodRepositoryInterface. `return new T().getType()` does not work so I wanted to use reflections. And here i followed [Get type of a generic parameter in Java with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901164/get-type-of-a-generic-parameter-in-java-with-reflection) which resulted in this mess:

```java
public interface FoodRepositoryInterface<T extends FoodInterface> {

   default String getType() {
        var genericTypeClass = getClass();
        var foodRepositoryInterfaceClass = genericTypeClass.getGenericSuperclass();
        var castedFoodRepositoryInterfaceClass = (ParameterizedType) foodRepositoryInterfaceClass;
        var arguments = castedFoodRepositoryInterfaceClass.getActualTypeArguments();
        Class<T> persistentClass = (Class<T>) arguments[0];
        try {
            return persistentClass.getConstructor().newInstance().getType();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    };

}
```

Running that, I got `java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Class cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType (java.lang.Class and java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')` in the last code block. So I looked onto the classes that were actually in the variables:
[image: actual variables]

I expected `IceCream` and `FoodRepositoryInterface` but not `Proxy` and `Proxy151`. It explains why the casting fails. I think this has something to do with Spring and Spring AOP. In the Proxy variable I couldn't determine any hint to the IceCream class or the FoodRepositoryInterface class.

What do I need to do here to get my IceCream.class?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with another workaround:

```java
    Class<? extends FoodRepositoryInterface> genericTypeClass = getClass();
    Class<T> persistentClass = (Class<T>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveType(FoodRepositoryInterface.class.getTypeParameters()[0], genericTypeClass);
```

The GenericTypeResolver is from `org.springframework.core`. The workaround is based on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202329/18427492

I still don't understand the proxy-thing but this workaround is fine for me. Maybe someone can provide a solution for others that can't use the GenericTypeResolver.