# ArrayList reflection

Tags: java, reflection, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out what type each object is in a ArrayList<Object>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106336/how-do-i-find-out-what-type-each-object-is-in-a-arraylistobject)
>   [Knowing type of generic in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886677/knowing-type-of-generic-in-java)

How can I retrieve the Type `Foo` from my `ArrayList` using the reflection in Java?

```
ArrayList<Foo> myList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
```

Comment: Type erasure --> can't get generic type at runtime!

Comment: Well you can't using reflection BUT, let's think outside the box for a while, what's the class of the first element of your ArrayList<>()?? ^^

Comment: @jlordo Unless it's a [`Field`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType())

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886677/knowing-type-of-generic-in-java/1886728#1886728

Comment: @BrunoVieira no, that is bad thinking! The first (or any other) element might be a descendant of the class `Foo`!!!

Comment: Or, the list might be empty.  That kind of approach is dangerous and fragile.  Find a better way to avoid reflection entirely.

Comment: I need to use reflection because I need to implement `Parcelable` interface in some objects with about 100 fields each. Do you know a quicker and more flexible way than reflection? @LouisWasserman

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't get this type from the value, but you can get it from the Field information.

```
public class Main {
    interface Foo { }
    class A {
        List<Foo> myList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    }
    public static void main(String... args) throws NoSuchFieldException {
        ParameterizedType myListType = ((ParameterizedType) 
                                A.class.getDeclaredField("myList").getGenericType());
        System.out.println(myListType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
    }
}
```

prints

```
interface Main$Foo
```

Fields, method arguments, return types and extended classes/interfaces can be inspected, but not local variables or values

These produce the same result.

```
List<Foo> myList = new ArrayList();
List<Foo> myList = (List) new ArrayList<String>();
```

You cannot obtain a generic type for

```
List myList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
```

Comment: If your list is actually in a class-level field, and if the type of that field has specific, non-generic literal type arguments.

Comment: +1 I had to dig this information out once.