# generics in java : identify Type of T

Tags: java

I am writing some generic `DAO` as follows

```
public class MyGenericDAO<T> {

      Class<T> clazz;

      public void doSome(){
        for(int =0 ;i<14;i++){
            //do something
           }
      }
}
```

Now i want to initialize clazz based on Type of T? .How can i do it?

For example if someone does `MyGenericDAO<Xyz> = new MyGenericDAO<MyGenericDAO>()`  then type of `T`  should be `Xyz`.

How can i do it?Is it possible without refelection?

Comment: You cannot do this without reflection.

Comment: @MattBall sounds like you can post that as an answer (preferably with explanation)

Comment: Of course it's not possible without reflection. Identifing this kind of info is what reflection does.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1901275/139010 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/1886728/139010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not even possible with reflection, unfortunately. If you need it, you'll need to make a `MyGenericDao` constructor that takes a `Class<T>` argument:

```
public MyGenericDao(class<T> clazz) {
  this.clazz = clazz;
}
```

Comment: if i do that? what is the use of having T in declaration of class?I mean why have MyClass<T> ??

Comment: @user93796 so that the compiler could check the `T` in `MyClass<T>` to be the same as the `T` in `MyGenericDAO<T>`.

Comment: But someone can do this right MyClass<Xyz> myobj = new MyClass<Xyz>(Abc.class);

Comment: @user93796 Nope, the compiler will flag that as an error. Only `MyClass<Xyz> myobj = new MyClass<Xyz>(Xyz.class);` would pass.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, due to the *type erasure* the only way to initialize `clazz` to the type of `T` is passing the corresponding class in the constructor:

```
MyGenericDAO(Class<T> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
}
```

Once of the reasons why `java.lang.Class` has been made generic is precisely to support this pattern. Since the `T` in `Class<T>` must correspond to the `T` in `MyGenericDAO<T>`, the compiler will be able to do the type checking for you.

Comment: That's really not entirely true. See my 2nd comment on the OP.

Comment: @MattBall I saw it, and I was intrigued for a moment, but unfortunately it does not help much, even after a relatively honest hack ([link](http://ideone.com/nyei5D)). I expected it to print `Integer` and `String`, but got instead only `T` and `T`. Considering the type erasure, it kind of makes sense.

Comment: Huh, I _really_ thought there was [an anonymous subclassing hack you could use](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860), but indeed I can't seem to use it here.

Comment: Super type tokens don't work that way. The trick named by @MattBall requires a (anonymous) subclass which the type argument stored in actual bytecode [DEMO](http://ideone.com/1CzZOz)

Comment: @Raffaele yes, that's exactly what I had in mind. For some reason that doesn't work with my local Java 6 installation (`ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType`).

Comment: @Raffaele I tried using an anonymous subclass ([see the link that I posted in the comment above](http://ideone.com/nyei5D) - the subclass is in the implementation of the `getTypeParameter` method), but unfortunately it does not work this way. Making an explicit anonymous subtype the way that your demo does is very cute, but it is unlikely to help getting the `T` of the `MyGenericDAO<T>` in the OP's situation.

Comment: @MattBall I bet you have missed a pair of curly braces after `new TestDto<String>()` in Raffaele's demo :):):)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes, that's exactly it. I'd tried to do the same at runtime, though my types done got erased. http://ideone.com/vFLHZQ

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I forked your code to quickly make mine, so I saw it :) I hope it's clear why it doesn't work: if you inspect the bytecode of `TestDto$1.class` (the anonymous class defined inside your `getTypeParameter()`) it can't contain any reference other than `T`. Instead when my code is compiled, two classes are synthesized (should be `Main$1.class` and `Main$2.class`) and the bytecode contains literally the references to `String` and `Integer`

Comment: @Raffaele Yes, it is absolutely clear why it does not work the way that I tried it, although I hoped for a moment that there's some reflection magic that I did not understand.

Answer (score 0):

Type arguments don't get to the runtime, so the calling code must pass a *token* to construct the `Class<T>` object at runtime. I name it *token* because there are many different objects you can pass to rebuild a `Class<T>` object at runtime, for example:

- a `String`, to be used with `Class.forName(name)`
- a `Class<T>` object
- a *type token*, ie a subclass of a parameterized type whose arguments are neither type variables nor wildcard (bounded or not), for example a `new List<String>(){}` (I used `new` and the curly braces to underline that this expression returns an instance of an anonymous subclass)

With type tokens:

```
public class MyGenericDAO<T> {

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public Class<T> getTypeParameter() throws Exception {
    Type type = ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
           .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    return (Class<T>) type;
  }
}
```

Note that there is an unchecked conversion when you cast the `Type` to a `Class<T>`. The calling code then looks like:

```
MyGenericDAO<Foo> dao = new MyGenericDAO<Foo>(){};
// Then if you want an instance
Foo foo = dao.getTypeParameter().newInstance();
```

Again, note the curly braces, since super type tokens only work when there is a **real class** generated at compile time. This approach only works if the client code honors the contract and uses an anonymous inner class every time a DAO object is needed (otherwise the magic of `getTypeParameter()` vanishes)